# How cat I pass routerLink to <div [innerHTML]=""></div> without WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss?

Tags: angular

In a parent component I use a same construction:

```
const link = `<a routerLink="${group.id}">${group.name}</a>`; // tried [routerLink] instead as well
```

And in a child component I try to work with it like so:

```
<div [innerHTML]="link"></div>
```

And, I get an error **WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content, see https://g.co/ng/security#xss**

Answer (score 1):

Yeah well you're not supposed to do that.

```html
<div>
  <a [routerLink]="[group.id]">{{ group.name }}</a>
</div>
```

Is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks for correct approach, in other time I'll exactly use it. But now I need to pass html to child component. If you know how to do it, please share with me.